# Single user input software that uses a lot of computational resources

Tags: linux

I am in need of program with the following characteristics:

- uses a lot of computational resources
- uses a single data input file for its task
- no user interaction with the software before seeing the results

It should run on Linux.

Gaussian is similar to what I need: user input's data file, it makes calculations and produces out a log file which then could be shown to the user.

I’m in need of this because I'm making an example software, where user just gives the input file and selects a VM on which to run it, then he is presented with the result file. (That's why I need program where user does not interact after giving the job).
It is quite difficult to find such programs, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "I am in need of programs similar to Gaussian"

Comment: So you basically want to have a program that uses as much system (hardware) resources as possible. Correct?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. The main problem though is that SR is designed for **specific** recommendations with questions that have a well defined feature set (even if it is one narrow feature in some cases); so basically you need to narrow this down severely.

Comment: I still don't gent your Gaussian reference. Are you talking about Gaussian Mixture models? About the Gaussian algorithm for solving linear equations? The Gaussian distribution? I think you might currently have one program that you call "Gaussian". However, if you don't describe your problem properly you cannot expect good answers.

Comment: What kind of resources should the program use? CPU time — single CPU or parallelized? RAM? Disk space? Other?

Answer (score 8):

If the term you are looking for is stress test (either for [hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_test_(hardware)) or for [software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing_(software))), you can use:

### Bash only

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```

or for multiple cores:

```
fulload() { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null & }; fulload; read; killall dd
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2927364/562769

### Stress

Debian has a [`stress`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/stress.1.html) package.

### Use input data

If you really want to use input data, I can recommend my matrix multiplication programs:

https://github.com/MartinThoma/matrix-multiplication

Most of the scripts are only able to use one core. They take one input file with the matrices A and B and generate output (C := A * B). The matrices A and B can be as big as you want (I've tested it with 2000x2000 matrices). You can create them with [createMatrix.py](https://github.com/MartinThoma/matrix-multiplication/blob/master/createMatrix.py) (even that might take a while when you want very big matrices)

The easiest to use might be [ijkMultiplication.py](https://github.com/MartinThoma/matrix-multiplication/blob/master/Python/ijkMultiplication.py):

```
python ijkMultiplication -i inputmatrices.txt > outputmatrix.txt
```

Comment: Updated my question. Sorry I left it ambiguous, hope it's more clear now what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user3501221 I've also updated my answer.